# How do you create your own DataType?

Tags: c#

I would like to create my own `DataType` called `positiveInteger`.

I know what you are thinking?

You are thinking that I should use `uint` here.
But `uint` contains `0` and I want only positive numbers.

Now you may tell me that Create a class called `positiveInteger`.
Yes, I can create a `Class` called `positiveInteger`but I don't know how to implement that class such that this new DataType accepts only positive integer values?

Comment: What should happen if you try to enter 0 into your datatype? Throw an exception, silently increase to 1, ...

Comment: Most likely I would like to throw an exception

Comment: For things like this consider a `struct` instead of a class.

Comment: @DourHighArch Why? can you explain me?

Comment: Structs are better for small and simple data stores because of they way they work at a binary level - they're value types instead of reference types. The semantics of this are very deep and something to read up on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: Structs implement value equality by default, so `(new PositiveInteger(1)) == (new PositiveInteger(1))`. Classes do not do this by default. Yes, you can override these defaults, but this is probably what you want to implement and is what programmers expect if they see a `struct` definition.

Comment: @DourHighArch I have used LionAM's answer which already uses struct and you just mentioned that Structs implement value equality by default, then why should I implement IEquatable<PositiveInteger>?

Comment: Because some .NET classes (like `Dictionary<T>`) use `IEquatable<T>` instead of `.Equals()`, and implementing it will make those classes use value equality. Admittedly, in `struct`s those are the same thing, but it's a good habit to get into because this is not the case with classes, and I think the default `struct ==` equality comparer uses reflection and is slightly slower.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thanks for the explanation. I will implement it as mentioned in the edited accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example imlementation could be:

```
public struct PositiveInteger : IEquatable<PositiveInteger>, IComparable<PositiveInteger>
{
    public PositiveInteger(uint value)
    {
        if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        _value = value;
    }

    public uint Value { get { return _value == 0 ? 1 : _value; } }
    private readonly uint _value;

    public static implicit operator PositiveInteger(uint value)
    {
        return new PositiveInteger(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator uint(PositiveInteger value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static PositiveInteger operator +(PositiveInteger value1, PositiveInteger value2)
    {
        var result = value1.Value + value2.Value;
        if (result < value1.Value || result < value2.Value)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();    //overflow
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static PositiveInteger operator -(PositiveInteger value1, PositiveInteger value2)
    {
        if (value1.Value < value2.Value) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value1.Value - value2.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is PositiveInteger == false) return false;
        return Equals((PositiveInteger)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(PositiveInteger other)
    {
        return Value == other.Value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Value;
    }

    public int CompareTo(PositiveInteger other)
    {
        if (Value == other.Value) return 0;
        return Value < other.Value ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

And a small test:

```
void Test()
{
    var list = new List<PositiveInteger> {5, 1, 3};
    list.Sort();  // 1,3,5

    var a = new PositiveInteger(1);
    var b = new PositiveInteger(2);

    var c = a + b;    // = 3
    var d = c - b;    // = 1
    var e = d - a;    // throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
```

Comment: The only changes I would make is have it take in and store internally a `uint` instead of a `int`. However if you do that you may need to make the functions explicitly [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx). to handle the `a - c` case.

Comment: @Aarvol Gave a good answer, but your answer is more valuable.

Comment: I have tried to use your code but I can see that I don't get compile-time error checking.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I fear that this is not possible.

Comment: Can you explain me the reason?

Comment: I'll +1 this if you implement `IEquatable<PositiveInteger>`.

Comment: The constructor takes a uint, and 0 is a valid uint value which can be passed into the constructor. The problem is that the compiler will not evaluate the what happens inside it. In theory he could, when you use a constant value, but I don't think that it is implemented this way.

Comment: @DourHighArch: added IEquatable<PositiveInteger> and IComparable<PositiveInteger>

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to "accept" values, which are ([mostly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx)) compiled as constant `int` values, then you'll need to implement an [`implicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion to `positiveInteger` from `int`

```
public class positiveInteger
{
    public static implicit operator positiveInteger(int source)
    {
        if(source <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to assign a positiveInteger like so

```
positiveInteger number = 5;
```

It will also, however, make it possible to assign an `int` value

```
int i = 5;
positiveInteger number = i;    // This will throw an exception when i <= 0
```

Comment: Important note, this will behave very different than how a `int` will behave when passing it around to functions because it is a class not a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your constructor.  But it is still not a good idea because you should still validate all data before you use it.  Just like checking that a denominator is not zero before blindly dividing.

```
public class PositiveInteger {
    private uint _value;

    public PositiveInteger(int x) {
        if (x < 1) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value.  Value is not positive.");
        }
        _value = x;
    }
}
```